# find M matrix given two matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

let us suppose that  we have two matrices, $A$ and  $B$  ,  let us suppose that eigenvalue decomposition of  $A$ is given by

$A=V*E*V^{-1}$

now let us suppose  that diagonal matrix  was multiplied by some constant  $\alpha$, we have  new diagonal matrix $E_1=\alpha*E$ and  create another matrix $B$ by apply

$B =V*E_1 *V^{-1}$

then we have  $A*B=B*A$

**proof :**

$A*B=V*E*V^{-1} *V*(E*\alpha) *V^{-1} =V* \alpha*E^2*V^{-1}$

$B*A=V*(E*\alpha) *V^{-1} *V*E*V^{-1}=V* \alpha*E^2*V^{-1}$

**my question is following : for such two matrix how to find  $M$ so that we have**

$A =M^{-1}*B*M$

Comment: We have $B = \alpha A$. So, of course $A$ and $B$ commute. Moreover, if $\alpha\neq 1$ and $A\neq 0$ you cannot find such a matrix $M$.

Comment: why?what is reason/?

Comment: Because $A = M^{-1}(\alpha A)M$ implies that $A$ and $\alpha A$ have the same eigenvalues. But the eigenvalues of $\alpha A$ are $\alpha\lambda_i$, where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: so that means that there is no two similar matrix, which share same eigenvector structures?

Comment: they  share only same eigenvalues?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "eigenvector structures".

Comment: two matrix  which  i  have got just multiplying  diagonal matrix by some constant, they have same eigenvectors, similar matrix have same eigenvalues right?so that means that similar matrix can't have same eigenvectors, that is what i meant , thanks

Comment: Right, not entirely (unless $A = B$). If $A=M^{-1}BM$, then if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $Mx$ is an eigenvector of $B$ because $BMx = MAx = M(\lambda x) = \lambda Mx$. So, if all eigenvectors are the same, then $M$ must be the identity.